# How to fetch array data from Google Firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want to fetch data from Firebase Realtime Database which is kept as an array. How can I fetch the data in 'amount' in 'productcarteditem'?

```
 export class ViewcartdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public alldetails: any;
  public id: string;
  // public replays: any;

  constructor(
    public acivatedroute: ActivatedRoute,
    public firestore: FirestoredatabaseService
  ) {
    this.id = this.acivatedroute.snapshot.params["id"];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.alldetails = this.firestore.detailscart(this.id).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"> {{(alldetails | async)?.productcarteditem.amount}} </div>
</div>
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTvB4.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTvB4.png  image of firebase

Answer (score 0):

Assign to a variable and use it

```
<div class="col-md-6"  *ngIf="alldetails | async; let item"> 
   {{item?.productcarteditem.amount}} </div> 
</div>
```